# On particular type of Gaussian primes.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a problem which I though about for a long time but I have no clues as to how to solve it.
[image]

So what can we say about this function .I just don't know anything about it . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) :

> *The positive integer Gaussian primes are the prime numbers that are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.*

How so ? Because of [*Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares). As for *f*, see [*prime $\zeta$ function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) and the [*Dirichlet L-function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function).